# Inner ng-repeat inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to ask how to use in right way inner ng-repeat inside of the outer ng-repeat:

It means taht u would like to use something like this:

```
  <tr  ng-repeat="milestone in order.milestones">
            <td>{{milestone.id}}</td>
            <td>{{milestone.milestoneTemplate.name}}</td>
            <td>{{milestone.actual}}</td>
            <td>{{milestone.estimate}}</td>
            <td>
              <span ng-repeat="milestoneTemplate in order.milestones.milestoneTemplate">
                {{milestoneTemplate.warningAttributes.id}}
              </span>
            </td>

            <td><a href="" ng-click="removeProjectFromTeam($parent.selected=$index)">{{ 'remove' | translate }}</a></td>
          </tr>
```

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 4):

Since `milestone` is already iterating over `order.milestones` in the top loop, simply do:

```
ng-repeat="milestone in order.milestones"
    ng-repeat="milestoneTemplate in milestone.milestoneTemplate"
```